# How does gcc handle -Wtype-limits?

Tags: c, gcc, types

I'm testing a small code snippet with *gcc 4.4.5* and `-Wtype-limits` option on.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* With other values of v, the behavior of the compiler is the same. */
    uint16_t v = 0; 
    assert((unsigned int)INT_MAX < (unsigned int)v); /* l. 7 */
    return 0;
}
```

Then, the compiler throws me the following warning:

`main.c:7: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type`

However, as far as I know, `INT_MAX` may be equal to `+32767` (from *C11 (n1570), § 5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types `<limits.h>`*). In that case, the variable `v` would be able to hold the value `INT_MAX+1`, and the expression in `assert` would be evaluated to `1`.

Therefore, I can see two issues:

- GCC takes in account my architecture, because, in fact, `INT_MAX` is not equal to `+32767`. In that case, it would reduce the benefits of `-Wtype-limits` for me.
- It is a bug.

What it makes me think about the second option is the following code, which doesn't produce any warning with the same options.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    assert((unsigned int)INT_MAX < (unsigned int)UINT16_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

So, what is the correct answer?

*PS:* By the way, I have to apologize because of my old version of *gcc*. Maybe the behavior of the next releases is different.

Comment: You want gcc to give warnings for any possible value of `INT_MAX`? Also I would expect this is all done after pre-processing so by the time it checks for this warning all it probably sees is a comparison between a variable and an integer constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GCC does take into account the actual known limits of the types. It knows that `int` is more than 16 bits wide in your case, so it warns.

You get no warning for

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    assert((unsigned int)INT_MAX < (unsigned int)UINT16_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

because the standard says in 7.20.2 (2):

> Each instance of any defined macro shall be replaced by a constant expression suitable for use in `#if` preprocessing directives, **and this expression shall have the same type as would an expression that is an object of the corresponding type converted according to the integer promotions.**

so with 32-bit wide `int`s, the macro `UINT16_MAX` is an `int`, hence the limits of the involved types don't guarantee that the comparison is always false (or true).